# How to invoke method with event from custom component

Tags: jsf-2.2, custom-component

I have my component :

```
public class Training extends UIOutput
```

and own renderer:

```
public class TrainingRenderer extends Renderer
```

with taglibrary:

```
  <tag>
    <tag-name>training</tag-name>
    <attribute>
        <name>style</name>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <name>action</name>
        <method-signature>java.lang.String action()</method-signature>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <name>listener</name>
        <method-signature>void actionListener(javax.faces.event.ActionListener)</method-signature>
    </attribute>
    <component>
        <component-type>training</component-type>
        <renderer-type>pl.spiid.app.spiidcharts.beans.training.Training</renderer-type>
    </component>
</tag>
```

and this is in my index.xhtml

```
<spiid:training rendered="true" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;" action="#{training.actionFromChart()}" listener="#{userBeanData.bindingMessage(arg1)}/>
```

and listening method

```
 public void bindingMessage(ActionEvent actionEvent) {...}
```

Method can be invoked by:

```
    Map<String, Object> attrMap = component.getAttributes();
    Object tmp = attrMap.get("listener");
```

I want to invoke this method with event argument. I think about using eventQueue, but I don't know how to use it correctly.

Using:
JSF 2.2.14

Edited.

Edit2:
Soon I will add a answer.

Comment: output components never fire actions afaik

Comment: What should I use ? UIInput?